# why does list.count returns 0 in this code

Tags: c#, .net, loops, infinite-loop

I want to find all the factors of this number and store the factors into a list but this list.count returns zero

```
    List<double> listOfFactors = new List<double>();
    public void FindFactors()
    {
        double num = 600851475143 / 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (600851475143 % i == 0)
            {
                listOfFactors.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }
```

Main function code

```
      class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Calculate cl = new Calculate();
        cl.FindFactors();
    }
}
```

Comment: @JeffMercado i called it in the main program and when i debugged it it showed list.count=0

Comment: @JeffMercado i am checking from 1 upto that number if it divides the number completely or not what is the problem with that

Comment: 600851475143 % 71 does evaluate to 0

Comment: Wouldn't anything mod 1 equal 0?

Comment: Ah right, I'm thinking backwards...

Comment: @yatrix if i run it in debug mode it includes one in the list and also 71 but not if i just run it, m new to this c# stuff, it might be a simple problem but i am stuck

Comment: See dbase's answer. Your loop will never finish, thus you'll never get back to a state where your code useful again. A number that big will take a while to loop and do an operation on if you changed to double or long.

Comment: @Yatrix I think the situation is deeper than that. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code gets stuck in an infinite loop.  The reason is that here `num` is 300425737571, but the maximum value of `int` is 2147483647.  The for-loop will never end.

```
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue);
Console.WriteLine(int.MaxValue+1);
```

> 2147483647
>
> -2147483648

**Edit #1**

That's 300 billion items to loop through.  Let's say (generously) that each iteration takes 100 instructions for the CPU.  That means about *30 trillion* instructions, which on a 2.5GHz processor should complete in about 1000 seconds (15 minutes).

**Edit #2**

Two hours later, it's complete.  You'll be pleased to know that the result is `15`:

- 71
- 839
- 1471
- 6857
- 59569
- 104441
- 486847
- 1234169
- 5753023
- 10086647
- 87625999
- 408464633
- 716151937
- 8462696833

Comment: But his list count should have been > 0, right?

Comment: @dbaseman it does not work even  if i replace int i with double i still problem?

Comment: @Yatrix yes, but we didn't see all the code, so I figured something else was up.

Comment: @dbaseman not working in long either

Comment: @Yatrix that's 600 billion ... I'm up to 8 billion so far, and `listOfFactors` is at 15.

Comment: @Yatrix how are you running it so quickly?  Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: I gotya. I was just going by him saying it was never incremented and it definitely should have been. I'm thinking it's in unlisted code. It will loop forever, but it should also add items.

Comment: No code. Just looking at it, you can see the list would get items.

Comment: Nice find. Think you nailed it.

Comment: @Yatrix what modification do i need to make to make it work?

Comment: I'm up to 74 out of 300 billion, and it's been like 40 minutes.

Comment: @dbaseman,@prabhakaran is there any way to complete this calculation quickly(programmaticaly)

Comment: @PradeepSingh Actually there is a way to do it more quickly, but I don't remember how; I had that as an interview question once.  I'd suggest opening a new question, I'm sure someone can give you the answer.

Comment: @PradeepSingh for one, you don't need to check the even numbers, right?  That will cut the execution time in half already

Answer (score 0):

I am a mewbie in java but the problem may be that you create the list for "double"s however you are adding some "int"s. Try to create the list for "int"s.

```
List<int> listOfFactors = new List<int>();
```

Comment: why does'nt it work then if i change int i to double i

Comment: you cant make i double. it is in the for loop. did you try yhe create a list for int s?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that actually you run this program till the end or there is something wrong with your debugging,  I reduced the num further by dividing it by two like this

```
for(int i=1;i<=(num/2);++i)
```

When the i crossed the limit of integer as indicated by dbaseman, at one time it reached zero,then it threw an error along the lines of  "zero is trying to divide the double" due to "600851475143 % i ". Check it out.

**EDIT:**

The above is the first hit. If you avoid the case when i is equal to zero, then here comes the further.

As 'dBaseman' said, it will reach minus value at some time. **Minus always yield 0 in mod operation(anything % -i =0). So all the integer value from -1 to -2147483648(this is the negative range of an integer) will yield to add one element in the list.**

Then i will come to positive side( again keep in mind that you are avoiding the case i as zero). Now again it will load some dividers into the list.

After some time again it will get into negative side again the filling will go on to add more 2147483648 elements. Now the list's count exceeds the short int's max value.

So **when you call the count minding that it is an integer, It will allocate a single byte but the thing it reads is double**. So the output is zero, because there is no proper conversion happening here(My assumption). Maybe .Net assumed that list count never go beyond the int limit. I hope this helps.